# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]:

Tags: spring, hibernate, runtime-error

Hi I am trying to learn Hibernate and Spring without maven. I try to get all the employee list from database and show list in jsp page. it returns below error.
any help will be great. thanks .

the error is :

Error 500--Internal Server Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at jsp_servlet.__employeelist._jspService(__employeelist.java:109)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:493)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:470)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
    ... 53 more
```

My context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


    <bean id="myDataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="com.oracle.hr"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  


    <bean id="d" class="hibernate.queries.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

and my hbm.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-4.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernate.queries.Employee" table="EMPLOYEES">
<id name="id" column="EMPLOYEE_ID">
<generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>

<property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME"></property>
<property name="lastName" column="LAST_NAME"></property>
<property name="eMail" column="EMAIL"></property>
<property name="hireDate" column="HIRE_DATE"></property>
<property name="jobId" column="JOB_ID"></property>




</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you provide the specified dependencies (pom.xml, gradle config file)?

Comment: i am not using maven or gradle so i dont have config file or pom

Answer (score 0):

Your error stack trace contains

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean]
```

So it cannot locate the  class "org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean".
The class "LocalSessionFactoryBean" actually resides in spring-orm jar and the fully qualified name are following depending upon which version of hibernate you are using.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
or
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
or
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

Instead of

```
<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

you have to use

```
<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

Comment: i use hibernate4 and in my orm jar all type of hibernate is exist.

Comment: I have updated the actual bean definition you to use in my answer.